# Network unstable after Windows 8 update

Tags: networking, windows-8

After updating from Windows 7 to Windows 8 on a machine of a friend we encounted severe network problems.

After turning the PC on, the network is mostly not functioning ( in 90% of the boots, the network doesn't work, the other 10% it's there as you would expect ). Disabling the adapter and re-enabling it sorts the problem out. Nevertheless this is not convenient and I would like to find a solution.

The network adapter is a `VIA Rhine`. Unfortunately I'm not a hardware guy, so maybe I'm missing some detail to analyse. If so, please comment and I'm looking after it.

**More Details:** The ports lights are on. The assigned IP comes from the pool Windows uses when there is no DHCP server available or no cable plugged in. As the IP is wrong I can't ping the router.

The IP should be assigned dynamically using the router provided by the ISP.

Comment: "The network is not functioning" is not a very good problem description. Does the port light come on? Does the machine get assigned an IP address? Can you ping the router?

Comment: @David Schwartz Added info in the question

Comment: Are you using dynamic or static IP on the machine?

Comment: @Sascha - What exactly do you mean by "mostly not functioning" either something is working or its not working.

Comment: @Ramhound : Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Presuming it’s just the one machine then and not the whole network… You’re best re-installing the NIC initially…

Is it a 802.11 or Eth interface card?